# Normal distribution and QQ plot

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have data that I plotted with a normal distribution and a QQ plot. I was wondering especially in QQ plot it seems that 95.4% of the data is normally distributed.

My question is what does numbers meanings that above 2 sigmas in QQ plot? Should remove them or I need to transform this variable and make it more normally distributed?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal distribution is a theoretical model of data. Empirical data can be distributed more similarily or more dissimilarly to a normal distribution.

That empirical data has a couple of notable divergences from a theoretical normal distribution:

- Presence of outliers
- Not symmetric
- Relative "peakedness"

Depending on your goal, you can pick a better model or transform the data to fit the normal distribution model. The power-law distribution might be a better model for the data. If you want to transform the data to better fit to a normal distribution, you can drop the outliers and then apply a log transformation.

Comment: Thanks that's an excellent explanation.